# Given $D \subset\mathbb{R}^{2}$ compact with $Area(D)=3$. If $f$ is continuous and $\int_D f=6$ then there exists $(x,y)\in\ D$ such that $f(x,y)=2$.

Tags: calculus, analysis

Show this to be true or false:

Given $D \subset\mathbb{R}^{2}$ compact with $Area(D)=3$. If $f$ is continuous in $D$ and $\int_D f=6$ then there exists $(x,y)\in\ D$ such that $f(x,y)=2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

False. Just take a $D$ that consists of two sets with positive distance of equal size $\frac{3}{2}$ and put $f=0$ on one part and $f=4$ on the other

Comment: If $f=0$ and $f=4$ does that still mean $f$ is continuous in D?

Comment: as long as there is a positiv distance between both parts, sure.